# Update the ObservableCollection from XML

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, listbox

I wanted to update my `ObservableCollection` in one of my Application. Whereas the XML file is written by some other Application. The problem isn't reading. The problem is reading the updated XML file.

### Details

Whenever an **AppA** instance has been created or has been launched it would create an entry in a SoftDevices.xml file with its details. Now in **AppB** I have listbox which is binded with an ObservableCollection which has been read from the same *SoftDevice.xml* file.

Letz say I have 3 instances of **AppA** has been running and then I open the **AppB**, I can see all the three instances in the listbox which shows me right details. Now while my **AppB** is running I again launch a new instance of **AppA**. It makes an entry in the XML file. But I cannot see any reflection in the listbox.

Can somebody help me to show the right path. I have tried using `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` on the listbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use a FileSystemWatcher : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx

With this class you get notified whenever a file is created/deleted or modified. In this last case, you can simply reload the XML file.

Comment: I don't see other technique, onestly, because your app must observe the file and eventually reload it. Is it possible for you to avoid the file? Maybe you can raise an event when a new instance of your app is launched (messaging? queue?)